# Why or why not should we use Java 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Currently I'm using Java jdk 1.6.0_26 for my eclipse based application. As now Java 7 is available, could I directly switch to Java 7 from Java 6?

If yes, what would be the impacts of it? If no, what are all the things should I look into so that I can switch to Java 7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java7 is awesome and everything, but do not switch to Java7 just yet. JIT compiler issue with the HotSpot VM of Java 7 which will be patched in Update2.

Read this:[Don’t Use Java 7, For Anything](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/)

Comment: That.. explains some strange bugs I had in some code. Fun quote: `These problems were detected only 5 days before the official Java 7 release, so Oracle had no time to fix those bugs, ` yeah it's not as if **not** releasing a completely broken build was worse than that xX

Answer (score 0):

The Java 7 issues are only for quite rare circumstances and are easily disabled.

I've run Eclipse with Java 7 Developers Preview since it came out and never seen any problems.

You should at least try to see if it works well for you.